# Using negative lookahead in ls(pattern = "") in R

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds, ls

Suppose I have the following objects in the memory:

```
ab
ab_b
ab_pm
ab_pn
c1_ab_b
```

and I only want to keep `ab_pm` and `ab_pn`.

I tried to use negative lookahead in `ls()` to list `ab`, `ab_b` and `c1_ab_b` for removal:

`rm(list = ls(pattern = "ab_?(?!p)")`

However, I got the error:

```
Error in grep(pattern, all.names, value = TRUE) :
  invalid regular expression 'ab_?(?!p)', reason 'Invalid regexp'
```

I tried my regex at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/), and found it matched all five object names, which suggested my regex was not "invalid", although it did not do what I wanted. My questions are:

1. Does `ls()` in R support negative lookahead? I know `grep()` needs `perl = TRUE` to support it, but do not see a similar argument in the `ls()` help documentation.
2. How to correctly select the three objects I wanted to remove?

Comment: After entering your regex and test strings at regex101.com, click "Save Regex" in the upper left. That will give you a URL you can use for your link that will allow readers to see your tests.

Comment: Thanks, Cary Swoveland for your tip! Will definitely do that in future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ab_?(?!p)` PCRE regex does not match as expected because of backtracking. It matches `ab`, then it matches an optional `_` and then tries the negative lookaround. When the lookaround finds `p` backtracking occurrs, and the lookahead is triggered again right before `_`. Since `_` is not `p`, a match is returned.

The correct PCRE regex would be `ab(?!_?p)`, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BEamQN/3). After matching `b`, the regex engine tries the lookahead pattern only once, and if it fails to match an optional `_` followed with a `p`, the whole match will fail.

`ls` does not support `perl=TRUE`, so it only supports the default TRE regex library that does not support lookarounds.

You may use

```r
ab([^_]p|_[^p]|.?$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BEamQN/1). *Details*:

- `ab` - `ab` text
- `([^_]p|_[^p]|.?$)` - either of the three alternatives:

  - `[^_]p` - any char but `_` and then `p`
  - `|` - or
  - `_[^p]` - a `_` and then any char but `p`
  - `|` - or
  - `.?$` - any one optional char and then end of string.

Comment: Thanks very much, Wiktor Stribiżew, for pointing me to backtracking - I'm fairly new to regex so will have to read more about it. Also thanks for shedding light on the correct negative regex. As I don't have the "any char but _ and then p" pattern in my object names, I simplified your solution as "ab(_[^p]|$)", which seemed to work on regex101.com. Please let me know if I overlooked anything. Many thanks again!

Comment: @elarry If `ab(_[^p]|$)` matches what you need, it is fine to keep. It just matches `ab` and then either requires end of string or matches `_` and then any char other than `p`. So, it won't match `ab_`, for example.

Answer (score 3):

`ls` uses `grep(pattern, all.names, value = TRUE)`, so it does not support perl extensions including lookahead. You can handle that externally, though, by wrapping `ls` in `grep`:

```r
vec <- ls(pattern = "^ab_")
# vec <- c("ab","ab_b","ab_pm","ab_pn","c1_ab_b")
grep("ab_(?=p)", vec, perl = TRUE, value = TRUE)
# [1] "ab_pm" "ab_pn"
```

So perhaps a one-liner:

```r
grep("ab_(?=p)", ls(pattern = "^ab_"), value = TRUE, perl = TRUE)
```

This does a double-`grep` (once inside `ls`, once outside); one can always just make it a little more direct with

```r
grep("ab_(?=p)", ls(), value = TRUE, perl = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks very much, r2evans, for your explanation! How did I not think of wrapping ls() in grep()! However, I wanted to select the other three variables for removal, so you only answered one of my questions. Thanks so much for your help anyway! :)